# Distribute items in a horizontal stack view with specified equal spacing in iOS

Tags: ios, uistackview

I checked all distribution types in a horizontal stack view (UIStackView), but I couldn't find one in which the first item starts at the leading of the stack view and all the other items have a constant (specified) spacing between them.

Basically my goal would be to have a table in which I have a stack view in each cell below each other and the items (doesn't matter how many they are) are horizontally aligned to the ones above and below them (the items are gonna be numbers, so an equal spacing between them is sufficient as they are gonna have the same width).

The closest is "Fill Proportionally", but the spacings are not constant. Also "Equal Spacing" option has the problem that the spacing changes according to the number of elements in the view due to the fact, that it fills the view.

Is there a way to make such kind of alignment of items in a stack view (or even without it)?

Answer (score 0):

UIStackView has a spacing property (constant), you should use this to set the space you want between the stack subviews.

From Apple Docs:

> var spacing: CGFloat
>
> The distance in points between the adjacent edges of the stack
>   view’s arranged views.
>   [UIStackView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStackView/spacing)

Hope It helps

Comment: But which distribution should I use? Cause even if I set spacing to a value and set distribution to e.g. "Equal Spacing", it still tries to fill the whole thing, and sets the spacing automatically like spacing property wouldn't matter. In other types of distribution it maters a bit (makes spacing more or less), but the spacing still changes according to the size of the container and the number of items in it. Is there a way to turn the effect of distribution style off?

Comment: Use fill, each subview will take its intrinsic content size